# Dealing with DB handles and initialization in functional programming

Tags: functional-programming

I have several functions that deal with database interactions. (like readModelById, updateModel, findModels, etc) that I try to use in a functional style.

In OOP, I'd create a class that takes DB-connection-parameters in the constructor, creates the database-connection and save the DB-handle in the instance. The functions then would just use the DB-handle from "this".

What's the best way in FP to deal with this? I don't want to hand around the DB handle throughout the entire application. I thought about partial application on the functions to "bake in" the handle, but that creates ugly boilerplate code, doing it one by one and handing it back.

What's the best practice/design pattern for things like this in FP?

Answer (score 1):

There is a parallel to this in OOP that might suggest the right approach is to take the database resource as parameter. Consider the DB implementation in OOP using SOLID principles. Due to [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), you would end up with an interface per DB method and at least one implementation class per interface.

```cs
// C#
public interface IGetRegistrations
{
    public Task<Registration[]> GetRegistrations(DateTime day);
}

public class GetRegistrationsImpl : IGetRegistrations
{
    public Task<Registration[]> GetRegistrations(DateTime day)
    {
        ...
    }

    private readonly DbResource _db;

    public GetRegistrationsImpl(DbResource db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

Then to execute your use case, you pass in only the dependencies you need instead of the whole set of DB operations. (Assume that `ISaveRegistration` exists and is defined like above).

```cs
// C#
public async Task Register(
    IGetRegistrations a,
    ISaveRegistration b,
    RegisterRequest requested
    )
{
    var registrations = await a.GetRegistrations(requested.Date);

    // examine existing registrations and determine request is valid
    // throw an exception if not?
    ...

    return await b.SaveRegistration( ... );
}
```

Somewhere above where this code is called, you have to new up the implementations of these interfaces and provide them with `DbResource`.

```cs
var a = new GetRegistrationsImpl(db);
var b = new SaveRegistrationImpl(db);
...
return await Register(a, b, request);
```

*Note: You could use a DI framework here to attempt to avoid some boilerplate. But I find it to be borrowing from Peter to pay Paul. You pay as much in having to learn a DI framework and how to make it behave as you do for wiring the dependencies yourself. And it is another tech new team members have to learn.*

In FP, you can do the same thing by simply defining a function which takes the DB resource as a parameter. You can pass functions around directly instead of having to wrap them in classes implementing interfaces.

```ml
// F#
let getRegistrations (db: DbResource) (day: DateTime) =
    ...

let saveRegistration (db: DbResource) ... =
    ...
```

The use case function:

```ml
// F#
let register fGet fSave request =
    async {
        let! registrations = fGet request.Date
        
        // call your business logic here
        ...
        
        do! fSave ...
    }
```

Then to call it you might do something like this:

```ml
register (getRegistrations db) (saveRegistration db) request
```

The partial application of `db` here is analogous to constructor injection. Your "losses" from passing it to multiple functions is minimal compared to the savings of not having to define interface + implementation for each DB operation.

---

Despite being in a functional-first language, the above is in principle the same as the OO/SOLID way... just less lines of code. To go a step further into the functional realm, you have to work on eliminating side effects in your business logic. Side effects can include: current time, random numbers, throwing exceptions, database operations, HTTP API calls, etc.

Since F# does not require you to declare side effects, I designate a border area of code where side effects should stop being used. For me, the use case level (`register` function above) is the last place for side effects. Any business logic lower than that, I work on pushing side effects up to the use case. It is a learning process to do that, so do not be discouraged if it seems impossible at first. Just do what you have to for now and learn as you go.

I have [a post](https://dev.to/kspeakman/what-is-the-benefit-of-functional-programming) that attempts to set the right expectations on the benefits of FP and how to get them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add a second answer here taking an entirely different approach. I wrote about it [here](https://dev.to/kspeakman/testable-back-end-programming-in-f-41n5). This is the same approach used by MVU to isolate decisions from side effects, so it is applicable to UI (using Elmish) and backend.

> This is worthwhile if you need to interleave important business logic with side effects. But not if you just need to execute a series of side effects. In that case just use a block of imperative statements, in a task (F# 6 or TaskBuilder) or async block if you need IO.

## The pattern

Here are the basic parts.

- Types

  - `Model` - The state of the workflow. Used to "remember" where we are in the workflow so it can be resumed after side effects.
  - `Effect` - Declarative representation of the side effects you want to perform and their required data.
  - `Msg` - Represents events that have happened. Primarily, they are the results of side effects. They will resume the workflow.
- Functions

  - `update` - Makes all the decisions. It takes in its previous state (Model) and a Msg and returns an updated state and new Effects. This is a pure function which should have no side effects.
  - `perform` - Turns a declared Effect into a real side effect. For example, saving to a database. Returns a Msg with the result of the side effect.
  - `init` - Constructs an initial Model and starting Msg. Using this, a caller gets the data it needs to start the workflow without having to understand the internal details of `update`.

I jotted down an [example](https://gist.github.com/kspeakman/0ecb30bfe8336e7b31bc71911ad22d9f) for a rate-limited emailer. It includes the implementation I use on the backend to package and run this pattern, called Ump.

The logic can be tested without any instrumentation (no mocks/stubs/fakes/etc). Declare the side effects you expect, run the `update` function, then check that the output matches with simple equality. From the linked gist:

```ml
// example test
let expected = [SendEmail email1; ScheduleSend next]
let _, actual = Ump.test ump initArg [DueItems ([email1; email2], now)]
Assert.IsTrue(expected = actual)
```

The integrations can be tested by exercising `perform`.

This pattern takes some getting-used-to. It reminds me a bit of an Erlang actor or a state machine. But it is helpful when you really need your business logic to be correct and well-tested. It also happens to be a proper functional pattern.